# How to use Eclipse (IDE) with Cygwin (Linux emulator)?

Tags: windows, linux, windows-7, cygwin

I apologize in advance for the stupidity of this question, but I am confused as h@&! and not even sure what to ask anymore.

For my math thesis - i.e., I am not a programmer - I have to write C code which uses the [CVODE library](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/description/description.html), which is part of SUNDIALS (do you need all that detail?). But I can't work directly on the Gentoo Linux cluster where the proram will ultimately run.

According to the SUNDIALS' website, CVODE has very rarely been compiled and used in a native Windows environment, but [it has been used using Cygwin](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/support/faq.html#inst_win). So I want to set up a C programming environment, including an IDE (especially a debugger), on my Windows PC, using Cygwin.

I have installed and executed the basic Cygwin (plus a package for nano editor) on my 64-bit Windows PC. I want to use Eclipse IDE, which is available for Linux and Windows, and can really only be used in a graphical interface (I think). I think I should set Eclipse up next (and then CVODE after that). That's what I'm trying to do now.

**My basic question is how do I setup Eclipse to work with Cygwin? What Cygwin packages do I need to run Eclipse?**

From the docs, I see that Cygwin has a server (Cygserver), but does not have a graphical interface. Or, it might have a graphical interface called Cygwin/X. *Do I setup Eclipse in Windows to communicate with Cygserver*, then do my work in Windows, but compilations and so forth would take place in the Cygserver? Or, *do I install Cygwin/X and use a Linux version of Eclipse* which, hopefully, works with Cygwin/X? If both are possible options, which is easier (I'm guessing the latter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin is nice but I've run into issues now and then with it. I would recommend that you download [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or some similar VM software and install the same Linux that is there on your production cluster inside it. Then you'll have an environment on your development machine which matches the production one.

Now, install eclipse (and anything else you want) inside the VM and you can develop the software there smoothly without worrying about tangential issues like cygwin and the rest.

Comment: +1 If you're targetting a linux cluster in the end, you'll run into far fewer issues if you develop on it from the beginning.

Comment: Yup. Emulation layers like Wine and Cygwin have lost almost all ground to virtualisation atleast when considering dev platforms.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling ([AT]Noufal) Is not possible. The cluster has no IDE (that I can determine) and I don't have full time access to it.

Comment: You don't need to bother with the cluster. I'm telling you to do everything on your Windows PC.

Comment: @Jeff The Eclipse IDE runs an all Platforms!? I'd install a seperate Linux anyway; developing on Linux is easier than on Windows. If your Cluster uses Gentoo, just download your free copy for your PC.

Comment: @Jeff What we're trying to say is this: use your own virtual box to write the code in an ide. Then, compile and deploy it to the cluster... no need to install eclipse out there.

Comment: @amon [AT]Lynn: Gentoo is exceptionally difficult to install (due to its nature). I don't have spare boxes, either. What do you think of Noufal's  suggestion (the other answer) to try VMWare?

Comment: @Jeff You're right, Gentoo is sick. Using VMWare or *VirtualBox* is a very good idea when you want to switch easily between Windows and Linux; you can sometimes even run windowed Linux applications on your Windows desktop. Any true Linux distribution will be be better/easier than using the Cygwin layer. Setting up Ubuntu is very easy and user-friendly, Debian Testing and Slackware are a bit more advanced. If you can't take the performance hit of a virtual machine, you can set up dual-boot, or even install Ubuntu as a Windows application: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer)

Comment: I took your advice. I've installed virtualbox. I'm attempting to install ubuntu into it right now (but I think it's hung). I will be compiling on this system, but no amount of tweaking will allow my PC to run the final program (it's heading for a big cluster), so performance not really an issue.